# Semantic errors with overload resolution for init-list-as-function-argument and templates

Tags: c++11, llvm, eclipse-cdt, initializer-list, template-argument-deduction

I've configured Eclipse CDT (Eclipse v4.5.0, build id 20150621-1200; CDT v8.7.0.201506070905) for C++11 use in its continual build process, but certain expressions are still causing semantic errors even though they compile properly using g++ 4.9.2 and clang++ 3.8.0. Namely, braced init lists supplied as function arguments are not matched to the arguments' corresponding `std::initializer_list` constructors and the right version of LLVM's `cast` function is not matched to its supplied arguments either. Is Eclipse CDT using an older, internal parser that doesn't support such C++11 functionality rather than delegating to the more modern external GCC toolchain, which it does detect?

```cpp
#include "llvm/ADT/ArrayRef.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Type.h"

using namespace llvm;

// i32 @myFunc1(i32, i32), i32 @myFunc2(i32, i32)
SmallVector<Function*, 2> getMyFuncs(Module& M) {
  Type* i32 = Type::getInt32Ty(M.getContext());

  // error #1 reported
  FunctionType* FT = FunctionType::get(i32, {i32, i32}, false); 

 // error #2 reported
  Function* F1 = cast<Function>(M.getOrInsertFunction("myFunc1", FT));

  // no error with implicit matching of ArrayRef(const std::initializer_list<T>&) here
  ArrayRef<Type*> ArgTypes = {i32, i32};
  FT = FunctionType::get(i32, ArgTypes, false);

  // error #2 reported
  Function* F2 = cast<Function>(M.getOrInsertFunction("myFunc2", FT));

   // no error with implicit matching of SmallVector(std::initializer_list<T>) here
  return {F1, F2};
}
```

Error #1

> Invalid arguments '
>   Candidates are:
>   llvm::FunctionType * get(llvm::Type *, llvm::ArrayRef, bool)
>   llvm::FunctionType * get(llvm::Type *, bool)

Error #2

> Invalid arguments '
>   Candidates are:
>   llvm::cast_retty<#0,#1 *>::ret_type cast(#1 *) std::enable_if::ret_type>::type cast(const #1 &)
>   llvm::cast_retty<#0,#1>::ret_type cast(#1 &)
>   '

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse CDT uses an internal C++ code analyser called `codan` so that it
can report what it deems to be syntax or semantic errors continuously,
not just at build time. It also diagnoses what it deems to be or static analysis
problems.

When `codan`s grasp of C++ is out of date w.r.t to your code and your compiler,
then your code will compile despite `codan`s gripes. In the **Problems** tab
at the foot of your IDE where diagnostics appear, you can distinguish `codan`'s
gripes from those of the compiler. A compiler gripe will always be classified in the
**Type** column as a *C/C++ Problem*. A `codan` gripe will have a type that
identfies one of codan's problem categories, e.g. *Semantic error*, 
*Code Analysis Problem*.

Another way to discount `codan` false positives is to look at the **Console**
tab, not the **Problems** tab, after a build. The **Console** tab reports the
toolchain's output.

But when the compiler is right and `codan` is up-to-date and still wrong you don't want its diagnostic
noise. As you would hope, you can configure `codan` to suppress it:-

- Navigate **Properties** -> **C/C++ General** -> **Code Analysis**
- Enable **Use project settings**
- Scroll down the **Problems** tree-control to the category 
  **Syntax and Semantic Errors**.
- Scroll on to the subcategory **Invalid Arguments** (that's the
  complaint cited in your *Error #1* and *Error 2*).
- Disable this subcategory by unchecking its checkbox and OK out.

Then *Error #1* and *Error 2* should go away next time the
the diagnostics tab is refreshed.

If you are unable to suppress all of `codan`'s false diagnostics by disabling
a few **Syntax and Semantic Errors** you can disable that entire category 
and just let the compiler find your compilation errors, old school.

Comment: I was hoping it wouldn't end up requiring that as I actually like being informed right away when I've used a wrong argument, but if there's no simple way of updating `codan` I guess that's the only thing to do if I want to keep using Eclipse with modern syntax and without false errors reported all over.

Comment: Oh, unchecking **Invalid arguments** doesn't turn off error #2, that requires unchecking **Symbol is not resolved**, which in turn results in method resolution errors if `auto` is used instead of the actual type (as the analyzer can't tell the return value is supposed to be based on the templated type). So annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse CDT contains its own C/C++ parsers, it does not use anything external. So, simply upgrading compiler won't bring anything new to Eclipse' completion.